# Why is the flex-wrap:wrap property causing my divs to get uneven sizes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I used flex box for my container and flex-wrap:wrap but my child divs are becoming uneven.How to fix it?

```
.container{

    margin: 0 auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;    
    padding:10px;
    display:flex;
}

.child{
    flex:1;  
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align: center;
    width:100px;
    length:100px;
    border:2px solid gray;
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    padding:65px;
    background-image:;  
    text-align: center;
}
```

Say like there are 11 child divs and it shows up in three rows. Now the last row displays only the remaining 3 divs out of 11 divs so it stretches those divs horizontally. 
[image: This is what I am getting]

So instead of that I am trying to keep all divs of same size and make the last row divs align center and same size. What to do?

Comment: Add the related HTML or make a snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Remove flex:1 and no need to float:left in flex box

Comment: Also in `.container` style `justify-content: space between;` and `align-items: center;` instead of vertical-align in `.child`

Comment: ok now all same sizes , but how to align it to the center of the container and the last row divs center of container as well?

Comment: Still aligned left

Comment: `justify-content: center;` plus a margin on `.child` for even spacing